# Android. When using the Github Rest Api, there are problems with verifying the token during authorization

Tags: android, get, authorization, retrofit, github-api

For educational purposes, I am creating a small application where the user has to enter his personal token. If it keeps the correct token, the repository will open, if it is incorrect, it will give an error.
I use the documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28
The documentation says:

You can authenticate your request by sending a token in the Authorization header of your request. In the following example, replace YOUR-TOKEN with a reference to your token:

curl --request GET 
--url "https://api.github.com/octocat" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR-TOKEN" 
--header "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
Note: In most cases, you can use Authorization: Bearer or Authorization: token to pass a token. However, if you are passing a JSON web token (JWT), you must use Authorization: Bearer.

If you try to use a REST API endpoint without a token or with a token that has insufficient permissions, you will receive a 404 Not Found or 403 Forbidden response.

My code:
AppModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(): String = "https://api.github.com/"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(BASE_URL: String): Retrofit {

        val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        return  Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

}
```

ApiService

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("users/{username}")
    suspend fun getUserInfo(@Header("Authorization") accessToken: String, @Path("username") username: String): Response<ResponseBody>
}
```

When I pass a token to the getUserInfo() function in the format: token = "Bearer MY_TOKEN", I always get code=401 in response, regardless of whether MY_TOKEN is correct or not

When I pass a token to the getUserInfo() function in the format: token = "MY_TOKEN", I always get code=200 in response, regardless of whether MY_TOKEN is correct or not

Although according to the documentation, if the token is incorrect, I have to send the code 404 or 403

I can't find where I made the mistake in any way. I tried to find a solution on the internet. But what I found did not lead to success